# Magento2 how to remove catalog product listing url with special characters?

Tags: magento2, catalog, catalogsearch, category-listing, listing

How to remove catalog product list url with unwanted string and special character for XSS Vulnerability fix, i need to completely remove the special characters if any.

Example : 'magento url'?attibute_code=%27%22%3E%3Cimg%20%20src=x%20onerror=alert(%27XSSBYTheSanjok%27);%3E

Like "magento url"?color=%27%22%3E%3Cimg%20%20src=x%20onerror=alert(%27XSSBYTheSanjok%27);%3E

Anyone got any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm curious how attackers able to do XSS with your code. Magento already supports protecting websites from XSS.

Comment: Hello Tu van , yes  we have been  reported vulnerability xss on one of the custom attribute. hence asked here for resolution.

Comment: What Magento version is your site using? Can you reproduce the issue on your site?

Comment: Magento version 2.4.4-p1 and yes I can able to reproduced in my local (Xampp)

Comment: I don't have version 2.4.4-p1 version so I can't test this issue at this time but I strongly recommend you upgrade your site (or your client site) to 2.4.4-p2. It is a security patches release that has small changes so it won't take time. And apply the security hotfix for CVE-2022-35698 https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-knowledge-base/kb/troubleshooting/known-issues-patches-attached/adobe-commerce-2.4.3-p2-2.4.5-security-hotfix-for-cve-2022-35698.html

Comment: Thanks, Tu van . please post this in answers section.

Comment: Back to your current issue, what special characters you are mentioning? `color=%27%22%3E%3Cimg%20%20src=x%20onerror=alert(%27XSSBYTheSanjok%27);%3E` is url encoded, the browser will decode it as `?color='"><img  src=x onerror=alert('XSSBYTheSanjok');>` which is not harmful.

Comment: As fas as I know, some code like alert won't make your site hurt

Answer (score 0):

`color=%27%22%3E%3Cimg%20%20src=x%20onerror=alert(%27XSSBYTheSanjok%27);%3E` is URL encoded, the browser will decode it as `?color='"><img  src=x onerror=alert('XSSBYTheSanjok');>` which is not harmful.

I strongly recommend you upgrade your site (or your client site) to Magento 2.4.5-p1 or at least 2.4.4-p2, it is a security patches release that has small changes so it won't take time. And apply the security hotfix for CVE-2022-35698 https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-knowledge-base/kb/troubleshooting/known-issues-patches-attached/adobe-commerce-2.4.3-p2-2.4.5-security-hotfix-for-cve-2022-35698.html

Comment: No. its not encoded and when i hit the site,  its alert with text.